# ng class using modulus in angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, algorithm

I used `$index` with modulus

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days" ng-class="{'col-xs-2':$index % 3 === 0}">
    <div class="days-group">
        <input id="{{day.value}}"type='checkbox' value="{{day.value}}" check-list='checked_days'> 
        <label for="{{day.value}}">{{day.name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

trying to proceed this markup http://pastebin.com/mWyezJDe

But they aren't the same, I can't figure out what is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way if possible:

```
    <div ng-repeat="day in days">
        <div class="col-xs-2" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0">
            <div class="days-group">
                <input id="{{day.value}}"type='checkbox' value="{{day.value}}" check-list='checked_days'> 
                <label for="{{day.value}}">{{day.name}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you missed a closing tag?

Comment: this is not working, it display the first block then the rest is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. What happen here is that col-xs-2 will be apply if condition [$index % 3 === 0] is true then

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days" ng-class="{true: 'col-xs-2'}[$index % 3 === 0]"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the paste-bin example, you basically have **3** divs having the 'col-xs-2' class; the first two holding **3** days and the last holding **1** day:

```
<div class="col-xs-2"><!-- mon., tues., wed./ --></div>
<div class="col-xs-2"><!-- thur., fri., sat./ --></div>
<div class="col-xs-2"><!-- sun./--></div>
```

In your ng-repeat version, you have **7** divs, each holding **1** day (and only three of them having the class="col-xs-2"); that is quite different!

```
<div class="col-xs-2"><!-- mon --></div>
<div><!-- tues --></div>
<div><!-- weds --></div>
<div class="col-xs-2"><!-- thurs --></div>
<div><!-- fri --></div>
<div><!-- sat --></div>
<div class="col-xs-2"><!-- sun --></div>
```

To get the effect you want, you need something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="daySet in [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6]]" class="col-xs-2">
    <div ng-repeat="dayNum in daySet" class="days-group">
        <input id="{{days[dayNum].name}}" type='checkbox' value="{{days[dayNum].value}}" check-list='checked_days'> 
        <label for="{{days[dayNum].name}}">{{days[dayNum].name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```